# C# .NET 5.0 MVC JWT Middleware authorization header

Tags: c#, jwt, token, middleware, httpcontext

The problem is that when I login in through the MVC controller post method, i get the JWT token and save it in the HttpContext authorization header, the code jumps to middleware where i can see the token in the context, but as soon as the invoke functions call _next(context) delegate, there is no more authorization header. How do i solve this? Is there some good practice how to pass the token from mvc controller to the middleware so i could attach account to the context?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that you need to set the SaveToken to true here:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    ...
    options.SaveTokens = true;
```

If not, can you post our startup class to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the token in HttpContext.Session solved the problem. Thanks though.